# How to delete email from gmail using python IMAP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, gmail-imap, imaplib

I am trying to read otp from mail and after that I want to delete that email from gmail option. I have no problem in reading email but I am not able to delete mail. I tried some code from stackoverflow. below is my code.

```py
def getOtpMail(vEmail, vPaasword):
    connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_URL)  # stablish connection with IMAP server
    try:
        connection.login(vEmail, vPaasword)  # Login with userid password
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return

    loopLock = True

    while loopLock:
        # fetch
        connection.select('"INBOX"', readonly=True)
        retCode, messages = connection.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')
        print(messages[0])

        latest = int(messages[0].split()[-1])

        res, msg = connection.fetch(str(latest), "(RFC822)")

        for response in msg:
            if isinstance(response, tuple):
                print('\n------------email--------------\n')
                msg = email.message_from_bytes(response[1])
                if SENDER_NAME in msg['From'] and KEYWORD in msg['Subject']:
                    loopLock = False
                # fetch required information
                    for part in msg.walk():
                        body = part.get_payload()
                        word_list = body.split()
                        index = word_list.index('verification')
                        otp = word_list[index + 3].strip('.')

                        #delete mail - below two line not working
                        connection.store(str(latest), '+FLAGS', '"[Gmail]/Trash"')
                        print(connection.expunge())

                        return otp
                else:
                    continue
```

I read documentation and print  `connection.expunge()` so I got response as `('NO', [b'EXPUNGE attempt on READ-ONLY folder (Failure)'])` . I think issue I have to establish connection in WRITE mode. I am not sure about it.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This question seems to be asking about how to delete mail using the [google mail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/delete), yet it is not tagged as such. You have not said what you have tried to do to solve it, or if have you tried debugging, provided any information about error messages, given any information about what library or platform you are using.  Please update your question with this information.

Comment: I don't want to use gmail api. I am trying to read and delete email using IMAP. I am able to read mail but not able to delete that mail. I also, mentioned comment in code which part is not working. I think you shall read question again so you will understand question properly.

Comment: You are right @ameya, I am sorry, I assumed it was an api question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In this issue, I opened mail box in readonly mode. Hence my program not able to write and store in IMAP server.
I changed

```
connection.select('"INBOX"', readonly=True)
```

to

```
connection.select('"INBOX"', readonly=False)
```

also I changed command type and flag type in store method -

```
connection.store(str(latest), '+FLAGS', '"[Gmail]/Trash"')
```

to

```
connection.store(str(latest), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
```

.